# How to make regex match only first occurrence of date?

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

Here is my string

```
28388 06/08/2016 06/08/2016 07/27/2016 00901683
```

Here is my current regex

```
([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})
```

Currently it matches all 3 dates. How can I have it stop once it has found the first one?

Comment: I got thousands of results by googling, please try it yourself there first. StackOverflow won't write answer for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly using the preg_match_**all** method. Guess if you just use `preg_match`, you'll be fine.

Comment: Are you sure OP is using PHP at all?

Comment: it says [tag:preg_match_all], which is a PHP tag (and a PHP function); if he isn't, he shouldn't be using the tag (see the tag's description). There might be functions of the same name in other languages, but PHP (as much as I *dislike* PHP) has "occupied" this tag.

Comment: that maybe the case, still your answer is a comment. Even I would suggest to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: no. It's an answer. Don't use `preg_match_all`, use `preg_match`, problem solved. As short as an answer can be.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue